# Error handling when parsing text file to object

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, error-handling

I want to parse a simple text file and create an object from the data it contains. I'm using C++11 for this (and I'm not fluent).

In case of any kind of error (e.g. missing file or invalid text) I wish to tell the caller of my parsing function what went wrong, providing information like what kind of error occurred and where in the file.

I don't consider exceptional that errors occur while parsing, so it seems exceptions are not the way to go.

I thought of returning a `struct` with all the info, including the resulting parsed object in case of success:

```
struct ParsingResult
{
    bool success;
    int errorCode;
    int errorLine;
    ParsedObject object;
}
```

However I'm not convinced by this solution because, in case of errors, I must still provide a `ParsedObject`. I can define a default constructor for that, of course, but by it's nature a `ParsedObject` makes sense only when the parsing is successful.

I could change `ParsedObject` to `ParsedObject*`, but I'm reluctant to use pointers when not necessary, and I wonder if this can be avoided.

My question: can you suggest a better solution to this problem? What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Obj
{
    // your object from the data...
}

struct ParseError
{
    int errorCode;
    int errorLine;
}

class Parser
{
    ParseError m_error;

    // other things
public:
    bool parse(const std::string& filename, Obj& parsedObject)
    {
         // Open file, etc...
         //parsedObject.property1 = some_value;

         // if something is wrong, set m_error and return false;
         // return true if ok
    } 

    ParseError getLastError() { return m_error; }   
}


// in your code
Parser p;
Obj o;
if(!p.parse("filename", o))
{
    // ParseError = p.getLastError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a

```
unique_ptr<ParsedObject>
```

or

```
shared_ptr<ParsedObject>
```

whose default constructor can be compared to null in case of unsuccessful parsing.

Avoiding raw pointers will free you from having to free memory :)